# How to wait for another value to be assigned to run .onAppear?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, cllocationmanager

I am learning to develop apps for iOS from scratch. And I chose SwiftUI to make an app that gets the location of the user, get with geocode the city where he is and with that information obtained, show a list of items that belong to that city from a API.

So, I learned on one hand how to get the location and on the other hand how to display a list. My problem now is that w**hen you run .onAppear(perform: loadData) to display my list, the "city" result is still empty**. Evidently the value of city is obtained after I try to display the list of the city.

Both the algorithm I have to get the location and the one I have to show the list work separately.

So my code is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Codable {
    var cinemas: [Cinema]
}

struct Cinema: Codable {
    var _id: String
    var cinemaName: String
    var cinemaCategory: String
}

struct HomeScreenView: View {
    
    @State var results = [Cinema]()
    
    @ObservedObject var lm = LocationManager()

    var latitude: String  {
        return("\(lm.location?.latitude ?? 0)") }
    var longitude: String { return("\(lm.location?.longitude ?? 0)") }
    var placemark: String { return("\(lm.placemark?.description ?? "XXX")") }
    var status: String    { return("\(lm.status)") }
    
    var city: String {
        return("\(lm.placemark?.locality ?? "empty")")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(results, id: \._id) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.cinemaName)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(item.cinemaCategory)
                }
            }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
        }
        
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://mycinemasapi.com/cinemasbycity/\(self.city)") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // update our UI
                        self.results = decodedResponse.cinemas
                    }
                    
                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            }
            
            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
LocationManager class

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
  private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  private let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
  let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

  @Published var status: CLAuthorizationStatus? {
    willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
  }

  @Published var location: CLLocation? {
    willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
  }

  override init() {
    super.init()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  }

    
  @Published var placemark: CLPlacemark? {
    willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
  }

  private func geocode() {
    guard let location = self.location else { return }
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (places, error) in
      if error == nil {
        self.placemark = places?[0]
      } else {
        self.placemark = nil
      }
    })
  }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.status = status
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.location = location
        self.geocode()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this without the full code. The problem is that when you initialize city, the LocationManager is not yet set. I would try making city a variable within LocationManager and set it during the init, and whenever you need to access it, call lm.city

Comment: @purebreadd I thought it was not necessary, but please check my update where I add the LocationManager class. Is in the init() of this class where you say to add lm.city? Could you tell me how you would do it and how you would use it later in HomeScreenView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by your code just do load data on placemark received, like

```
        List(results, id: \._id) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.cinemaName)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(item.cinemaCategory)
            }
        }.onReceive(lm.$placemark) {
            if $0 != nil {
               self.loadData()
            }
        }
```